# Oozie Spark Action (Containing Pyspark Script) Stuck in RUNNING

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

It's my first time trying to run a Spark Action containing a Pyspark Script in Oozie. 
*Please note, that i'm using cdh5.13 in my local machine (vm with 12G of RAM), and HUE to build the workflow.*

**The workflow.xml as follow:**

```
<workflow-app name="sparkMLpy" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="spark-c06a"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark-c06a">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>MySpark</name>
            <jar>sparkml.py</jar>
            <file>/user/cloudera/sparkml.py#sparkml.py</file>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

**I've also tried to add some options:**

```
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
```

**Here is the Pyspark script (it does pretty much nothing):**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sc=SparkContext()
log_txt=sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/CCHS.txt")
header = log_txt.first()
log_txt = log_txt.filter(lambda line: line != header)
temp_var = log_txt.map(lambda k: k.split(","))
c_path_out = "/user/cloudera/output/Frth"
temp_var.saveAsTextFile(c_path_out)
```

**Here is a view of the workflow in HUE:**

[View of the workflow in HUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ9xm.png)

**Here is the job.properties:**

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=True
send_email=False
dryrun=False
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
jobTracker=quickstart.cloudera:8032
security_enabled=False
```

When I run the workflow, it gives no error but it keeps running with no result (it's not even suspended). Here is a veiw of the logs below:

[View of the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deflf.png)

**I've tried to add the options bellow:**

```
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

And it is always stuck in running. When I verified the logs I found this warnings:

```
Heart beat
2019-01-04 02:05:32,398 [Timer-0] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler  - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2019-01-04 02:05:47,397 [Timer-0] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler  - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Can you please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run the same workflow on local (not yarn) and it works!

```
        <master>local</master>
        <mode>client</mode>
        <name>MySpark</name>
        <jar>sparkml.py</jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Cloudera VM for experiment and noticed that it behaves abnormally after few days of usage. The only way I manage to solve it by re-instantiating the Cloudera VM and the same started working. 
Even if you have a simple workflow with few parallelisms, it may work on time and it may be stuck after some time. It works properly using REPL, but using Oozie, it just gets hanged.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I'm wondering if I missed something in configuration, so that I can run pyspark in Oozie, isn't it?